# Couldnt find binary Calabash-Android when importing Android Library in ROBOT FRAMEWORK

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, android-library

Error observed:

```
FAILED AndroidLibrary Initializing test library 'AndroidLibrary' with no argumen
ts failed: Couldn't find binary calabash-android
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.p
y", line 184, in _get_instance
    return libcode(*self.positional_args, **self.named_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AndroidLibrary\__init__.py", line 46, in _
_init__
    'calabash-android'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AndroidLibrary\__init__.py", line 65, in _
env_command
    raise AssertionError("Couldn't find binary %s" % os.path.commonprefix(comman
ds))
FAILED AndroidLibrary Initializing test library 'AndroidLibrary' with no argumen
ts failed: Couldn't find binary calabash-android
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\lib\robot\running\testlibraries.p
y", line 184, in _get_instance
    return libcode(*self.positional_args, **self.named_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AndroidLibrary\__init__.py", line 46, in _
_init__
    'calabash-android'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AndroidLibrary\__init__.py", line 65, in _
env_command
    raise AssertionError("Couldn't find binary %s" % os.path.commonprefix(comman
ds))�
```

Please help to fix importing AndroidLibrary

ROBOT FRAMEWORK VERSION 2.8.2

Comment: Did you install that library?

Comment: No i have not installed, in https://github.com/lovelysystems/robotframework-androidlibrary, under "Prepare your app" section there is instruction to install calabash but is it a must to do that ? Because i was able to run without any errors in another system. Any command to check if CALABASH is installed ?